# Linq expression checkin if one user is following another

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that stores followers and followees.These are based on the guids they have.

before i want to make this relation i want to check and see if the person is already following the person

**EDIT**

`bool userExist = _databaseEntities.Users.Count(e => e.UserName == followerName) > 0;`

```
        if(userExist)
        {
            var user1 = _databaseEntities.Users.FirstOrDefault(y => (y.UserName == username));
            var user2 = _databaseEntities.Users.FirstOrDefault(z => (z.UserName == followerName));
```

So i get two users and check if they are there and then check if their userIds are in the table of followers forming a relationship.

so I have this `_db.Followers.Count(c => (c.UserId == user1.UserId && c.FollowerId == user2.UserId) < 0 );`

but it always comes out as 0 even if the relation is there

How can i do this right?

Comment: Why are you compating `bool` with `0`? Your code: `(... && ...) < 0`

Comment: to make that a little more clear, move the  <0 outside the )  that is immediately to its right.

Comment: Comparing `Count` with `< 0` will ALWAYS be `false` :)

Comment: @NikolayKostov good point. You could just change count() <0 to !Any

Comment: i've tried doing the !Any but it gives me true all the time now even tho i use the same type of users 
`bool notRelation = !_db.Followers.Any(c => (c.UserId == user1.UserId && c.FollowerId == user2.UserId));`

Comment: What's user1 and user2 ? What's your input ? I think you need to rephrase that query altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you have a table like this:

```
 |  UserId  |  FollowerId  |
 |----------|--------------|
 |  Homer   |  Marge       |
 |  Homer   |  Lisa        |
 |  Marge   |  Homer       |
 |  Marge   |  Bart        |
 |  Bart    |              |
 |  Lisa    |  Bart        |
 |----------|--------------|
```

And the related User class should contain at least a string property for the UserId and a Collection of Users (those who the user is following)
So you can have a method inside User like this:

```
    public bool CanFollow(User followee)
    {
        return !Followee.Any(x => x.UserId == followee.UserId);
    }
```

It's easier and more logical and you simply use it like that

```
User homer = _db.Followers.Where(x => x.UserId == "Homer").FirstOrDefault();
User marge = _db.Followers.Where(x => x.UserId == "Marge").FirstOrDefault();

// can Homer follow Marge?
homer.CanFollow(marge);
```